# How can I sort excel file by the first column? java

Tags: java, mysql, sorting

i have to make a program where we read data from excel files as the one here [image]
 and store them in a table in mysql with descending ID. 
I have made the program to read the data and print them in console using APACHE POI, create the table by the first row of the excel file and then store the rest data. But the storing I would like to happen by their IDs. So I made a function where first I will read the first column where the IDs are and then read the rest data using LinkedHashMap.

How i would do the sorting in IDs?Could anyone help me? I have put spaces where i think the changes should be made.

Comment: Why you care about physical order of storing data in table ? You can very well get the data sorted in presentation by using `Order by` clause while picking up from the table !!!!

Comment: The database doesn't have to store it as you insert it, because you don't know how it organizes it's data.

Comment: You could just use `TreeMap` which support  natural ordering

Comment: I know that i can do it with ORDER BY but in my project should happen programmatically!

Answer (score 0):

Add each `TableRow` to your `List`. Use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) [sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method to sort the data and then iterate through it and insert.

You can customize the [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) to determine the order.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(TableRow o) {
    // for descending order
    return this.getID().compareTo(o.getID())*(-1);
}
```

Using [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), you can do something like this :

```
 new Comparator<TableRow>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TableRow o1, TableRow o2) {
             // for descending order
            return o1.getID().compareTo(o.getID())*(-1);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Could you help me with my program how i would do it?

Comment: and how i would write the Collections.sort?

Comment: `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` ... please refer the API .

Comment: Ok I've done the changes and looks fine. But when I ran the program i get an exception in here: tousRows.add(new TableRow(currentID, tableFields));
Could anyone know why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap. pass the id column value of the Excel sheet as the the KeyId for treemap. It will automatically sort your data ...

Comment: Could you help me how i would do this?

Comment: @efoikonom: Instead of **LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> tableFields = new LinkedHashMap(list.size());** use **TreeMap<Integer,String> tm = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();** And then tm.put(ID,AnotherValue); Something like that

Comment: use the following code as standalone to understand TreeMap        `import java.util.TreeMap;


    public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  TreeMap<Integer,String> tm = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
    for ( int i = 11; i > 0 ; i-- ){
     tm.put(i,"Am the value"+i);
    System.out.println("Next Row:"+tm.get(i));
    }
    for ( int i1 = 0; i1 < 11 ; i1++ ){
     System.out.println("Next Row:" + tm.get(i1));
         }
        }

    }`